# Best practice to store un-mutable data on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

I am looking to create a navigation based reference app for the iOS.

I have considered the following ways to store the data:

hard coding

plist file

some kind of comma delimited file

The data structure that I will be using has a bunch of strings, an array, and a reference to a picture.

What do you think the best way to store this data is without getting into CoreData?

Thanks

Also I dont think it would be more than 500 entries.

Comment: Use a property list. It's the best way to do it without Core Data.

Comment: Unless there are hard requirements against CoreData, I would strongly suggest taking a few hours to learn it. It's fast, easy and well integrated with CocoaTouch

Comment: Ill give CoreData a look over, any links you suggest besides the dry apple docs? Thanks

Comment: This youtube video was good http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qQmY97-qj9w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not a "best-practice" problem for any case.

> The data structure that I will be using has a bunch of strings, an array, and a reference to a picture.
>
> What do you think the best way to store this data is without getting into CoreData?

For your needs, I suggest you look into `NSKeyedArchiver`.

`NSString`, `NSArray`, and `UIImage` all know how to encode and decode themselves. Just use an `NSKeyedArchiver`. Note that the objects in your collections (e.g. `NSArray`) must adopt `@protocol NSCoding`.

If you need to open this on a mac, then convert the `UIImage` to `NSData` using a proper image file format representation (e.g. PNG or JPEG) because `UIImage` is not available.

In detail:

> hard coding

That could mean a number of things.

> plist file

You're working with large non-plist types. That would mean you would need to convert to and from `UIImage`<->`NSData` unnecessarily, which would add a lot of overhead -- memory, CPU,  and potentially file size. All these types can encode themselves better than (or as good as) a plist representation.

> some kind of comma delimited file

Your image will not allow that to happen (reliably).

Comment: When I say hard coding I mean have a ridiculously long method that would create all the data objects I need, add them to an array, and have the UITableView read from that array. Looking back it was probably a bad idea in general. Probably just good for testing.

Comment: However I would like to perform searches on these data objects. I see that CoreData offers indexing.               This video was a good tutorial on where to locate the sqlite file that the app will use. What I am looking to do will have no requirement for the user to add their own entries it will all be loaded from a file, its a simple reference app with favorites and search. Nothing special. Just dont want to slow the phone down so thats why Im looking for the most efficient way to load data and search.

Comment: @M Jesse ah, i see. that approach is relatively fragile -- no version support means you can never change it an always need to identify the version by the number of entries, while performing many conversions to and from `NSData`.

Comment: @M Jesse That's a much different problem. In that case, you'd typically just add the image files to the bundle and load/display them only when needed. The identifier for the image to load would be an `NSString` which specified the image by its name. In that case, you could by using a small plist, which simplifies development/edits.

Comment: Yea I think a plist is going to be appropriate for this app.. Is there a limit to the data that can be held on a plist?

Comment: not really a limit, but once the file grows large, it can take a lot of time and resources to read, parse, load, and create object representations of the contents. I'd attempt to keep it below 1 MB for a general case. Do save them as binary plists to minimize this. Obviously, your app will be killed or given memory warnings if it expands too large during deserialization.